# CSS selector on youtube comments doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to write a web scraping script to collect all comments on a youtube video (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7aDUFAAwFE), before all comments can be shown, I need to click the 'show more' button at the bottom of the comment section:

```
<span role="button" class="d-s L5 r0" title="Load more posts" tabindex="0">Show more</span>
```

however when I try to click it through javascript (or even find it in the browser debugging mode), the JS interpreter gave me an 'element not found' error. I've tried 'span.L5', 'span[role=button]' and 'span[title^=Load]' in both Chrome and Firefox but non of them returns any element. So the question is, how to select this button?

Comment: YouTube's comment section appears to be in an iframe (`div#comments-test-iframe > iframe`), so you won't be able to reach the button without entering the iframe's DOM somehow.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Such a simple question, I didn't notice that before as iframe was automatically imported by Google developer's tool